# How to remove the list of values from JSON object to another JSON object using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have two `JSON` Objects:

```
var A = { 'Header','Quotes','Returns','Indent','Basic',...,'Placing' }
var B = { 'Header','Quotes','Returns','Indent',... }
```

A and B share the same elements, `Header`, `Quotes`, `Returns` and `Indent` and so I need to remove them using jQuery.

A's Final Output should be:

```
A = { 'Basic','Placing',... }
```

Comment: Fixed grammar and code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge function:

var A={'Header','Quotes','Returns','indent','Basic','Placing'}
Var B={'Header','Quotes','Returns','indent'}

var C = $.merge(A, B);

Regards

Comment: For above solution 'C' showing all 'A' elements but my requirement only remove the B elements from A object and as of my understaning merge only working array of objects .Am I correct?